# Download a react component using jsPdf and html2canvas

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

i'm using html2canvas and jspdf  packages to download a simple component but when i click download i get a blank pdf page without any content and there is no errors in the screen,
that's my code:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import Pie from './Pie.js';

class Qu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  printDocument() {
    const input = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
    html2canvas(input)
      .then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
        // pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
      })
    ;
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
    
      <div id="divToPrint" className="mt4">
        <div>Title of Component</div> 
        <div><Pie /></div>
        <div className="mb5">
        <button onClick={this.printDocument}>Print</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}
export default Qu;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import Pie from './Pie.js';

class Qu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  printDocument() {
    const input = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
    html2canvas(input)
      .then((canvas) => {
        let imgWidth = 208;
        let imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        // pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
      })
    ;
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
    
      <div id="divToPrint" className="mt4">
        <div>Title of Component</div> 
        <div><Pie /></div>
        <div className="mb5">
        <button onClick={this.printDocument}>Print</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}
export default Qu;
```

Please try the above code.

Comment: hello, i have try this code but still have a blank pdf

Comment: thanks its working now after cleaning the cache, but it print just one pdf page , if the content of the component is more than one page its print the half of the page, any suggestion how to make it print more than one page ?

Comment: You need to compare the image height with page height and add pages manually. If you use a table, there's a jspdf-autotalbe plugin that supports multiple pages. But for text and images, you have to do the manual calculation.